# What is an "Insertion Fault"?

Tags: internet-connection, cable-modem, broadband

I'm having internet connection issue and after a long and painful phone call the engineer from my ISP (Virgin Media in the UK) has diagnosed that my Modem (Virgin SuperHub 2) is generating 2000 "Insertion Faults" (per day/minute/second? she was unclear on the rate, only the quantity) and that this is causing the loss of connectivity.

So, **what is an *Insertion Fault***?

I realise this might be company-specific lingo, a quick Google for Insertion Fault didn't give me much (not that I know what I'm looking for).

Update
More Googling leads me to [Insertion Loss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_loss) which makes more sense. I'm guessing she meant an Insertion Loss of 2000db. I'm guessing a loss of 2000 is bad, so a follow up question, what would be an Ok Insertion Loss? Bonus points for expanding on the subject with usual levels etc.

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.dslreports.com/faq/3407:

> More commonly called attenuation, insertion loss is the loss of signal
>   power between two points. Items that lead to signal loss are excessive
>   cable length, temperature, humidity, and excess return loss.
>
> All devices (such as splitters, amps, etc) that you add to a cable
>   line have insertion loss.

I have no idea about acceptable levels, but as a radio amateur I'd guess more than 70dB would be a real problem. I've read some sources on the internet that said 50dB is normal. Also keep in mind that dB is a logarithmic scale, so the difference between 70 and 2000 dB is huge. Perhaps 2000 dB is the maximum the equipment would indicate.

Comment: Thanks! It's starting to make a bit of sense. The outage has only been happening recently and usually in the afternoon. I think it might be down to the weather, it's been quite hot here in the UK, and to boot, the cable to the street has become exposed because of the shonkey job they made of the installation. I think the cable is maybe getting too hot in the sun and thus changing the characteristics of the cable. Maybe